# How to use knitr when there are some accented characters in path of directory?

Tags: r, path, knitr, non-ascii-characters

I am writing a function in R that allows to produce a html report for any list in R memory. The function relies on knitr. 
The function is available here:
[the ez.html function](https://github.com/NicolasStefaniak/easieR/blob/master/R/ez.html.R)
The function is working quite well, except if the path of the working directory contains special characters (e.g., accented characters). 
In other words, if path is :

C:\Users\Nicolas

everything is ok. However, if path is :

C:\Users\Véro

knitr is not able to change the directory. 
I found that the author of knitr urges [not to use special character in the path](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/issues/614). However, as I would like to share the function, I cannot ensure that other people does not use non-ascii characters. 
I tried to avoid the problem by testing whether the path contains non-ascii characters and to create a new directory when there is at least one ascii character.

```
wd<-getwd()

 if(grepl("[^[:alnum:]]", wd)) {
   wd.decomp<-str_split(wd, "/")
   special.chr<-grepl("[^[:alnum:]]",unlist(wd.decomp) )
   special.chr<-which(special.chr)[2]
   special.chr<-special.chr-1
   wd.decomp<-unlist(wd.decomp)
   new.wd<-wd.decomp[1:special.chr]
   new.wd.<-str_flatten(new.wd, "/")
   new.wd.<-paste0(new.wd., "/res.easieR")
   dir.create( new.wd., showWarnings = FALSE)
   test<-try(setwd(new.wd.))
  if(class(test)== "try-error"){
     new.wd.<-str_flatten(new.wd, '\\')   
     new.wd.<-paste0(new.wd., "\\res.easieR")
     dir.create( new.wd., showWarnings = FALSE)
     setwd( new.wd.)
    }
```

Once again, this code chunk is working quite well, except if you need the administrator rights to create a directory.

Thus, if the path is 
C:\Users\Nicolas\ça.a.marché
The function creates the following directory :

C:\Users\Nicolas\easieR.res

However, for

C:\Users\Véro

The function fails because administrator rights are required for creating 
C:\Users\easieR.res

Does anyone have an idea either to make knitr accept a path with accented character or to create a directory without special characters ?

Thanks all.

Comment: R has tempdir() that you can use to write the files if they are temporary.  So you can use `paste0(tempdir() , '\' , "easieR.res")` .  There is no need to keep switching the wd,  use the full path instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My problem seem solve (at least on the test I made).

Comment: I think @Elin is right that `tempdir()` is the way to go if you want to create a new directory with a valid path. However, I'd recommend *not* to (silently) change the directory at all: Very, very often things go wrong because users are not aware of their current directory (e.g. when trying to read data). Adding one additional layer of obfuscation probably won't help … My suggestion: Exit with a clear error message and ask the user to move to a valid directory.

Comment: thank you CL for the recommendation but it is not always possible, especially when users have accented characters in their name and when they do not have the administrator rights on the computer (for instance in classrooms in which students can only go in their folder, but are even unauthorized to change the name of their own folder). In short, I'm now using the solution proposed by Elin, but the problem is not totally solved yet for people with accented characters in their name